# ONVIF : How to form the DeviceIO web service address from the IP address of an ONVIF supported IP camera

Tags: ip, onvif

I have the IP address of an ONVIF supported  IP camera,how do I form the address of the DeviceIO web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust way to do it is the following:

1. Probe the camera, by using the WS-Discovery
2. Extract the field `XAddr` from the `ProbeMatch`. Usually it is `http://<ip_addr>/onvif/device_service`, but it is not guaranteed always to be like this.
3. Verify if your camera supports `GetCapabilities` or it has the new `GetServices`.
4. Either from `GetCapabilitiesRepsonse` or `GetServicesResponse` verify if your device supports the Device I/O service and get the corresponding `XAddr`.

Beware that the initial handshake may be tricky, because if the camera only supports UsernameToken for authtentication, you'll need to syncronize your client with the device's clock. Have a look at the ONVIF [Application Programmer's Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf) for further details.