# how to control exposure of ip-camera on Onvif using WSDL soap or Rest

Tags: rest, delphi, wsdl, ip-camera, onvif

how to control ip-camera's settings with ONVIF protocol standard such as exposure , bit rate , frames 
i use Delphi Tokyo 10.2  and use rest and web service soap WSDL

according to this topic :
[ONVIF : How to form the DeviceIO web service address from the IP address of an ONVIF supported IP camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427595/onvif-how-to-form-the-deviceio-web-service-address-from-the-ip-address-of-an-o)

ip of ip-camera is : 192.168.1.2
try to load address "http:///onvif/device_service" with http://192.168.1.2/onvif/device_service

i receive this error:

    `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl"`

Answer (score 1):

Look at this website

https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/

In section "Service specifications" the website discribes several WSDL files for diffrent types of services. There is also the documentation as PDF for that WSDL files.

You should use http://192.168.1.2/onvif/device.wsdl instead. But IMHO that is not the service you are looking for.